# How can i set Capture volume to specific value in rasberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, pulseaudio

I am trying to do livestream with my rasberry pi. So I am using the USB webcam inbuilt microphone. I can see in alsamixer, capture volume level getting high automatic when I start talk. So how can I fix the capture volume to a specific value.
[image]

I have tried "alsactl store" command but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To set the capture volume, first check capture is active:

```
amixer set Capture cap
```

Then set capture volume (for example 100%):

```
amixer set Capture 100%
```

It returns something like:

```
alpereira7@rasp:~$ amixer set Capture cap
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 39 [62%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 39 [62%] [12.00dB] [on]

alpereira7@rasp:~$ amixer set Capture 100%
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 63 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 63 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
```